# What is a good way to do multi-language sites in Umbraco?

Tags: seo, umbraco, multilingual

We are going to implement our site in both English and German. What is the best solution to redirect customers to the right site. I thought of having the domains like www.mydomain.com/en and www.mydomain.com/de. My question is what is the best way to redirect the user to the right site?

Should I have a landing page at www.mydomain.com where you could switch language, or should I simply look at browser settings and redirect to the appropriate version of the site?

Also are there any SEO issues with this setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is often to use two domains. And 2 site trees in Umbraco and set the Hostnames / Domains on the Tree. Thee domain name counts  for SEO.

It can also fine with one domain, a solution I use is on the www.mydomain.com you put a redirect to the /en or /de

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
    Layout = null;
}

@{
    var language = "";
    String[] userLang = Request.UserLanguages;
    if (userLang != null && userLang.Length > 0)
    {
        language = userLang[0];
    }

    if (language.StartsWith("de"))
    {
        Response.Redirect("de");
    }
    Response.Redirect("en");

}
```

This code is only check the language, you can also use a geo/ip database or set a cookie when you know the language. Depend om your situation. Do your visitor wants a landing page to choose a language? SEO does not matter whether you have it or not.

Comment: Response.RedirectPermanent is also fine, I chose to use redirect because the url depends on a variable. I guess it does not matter much for SEO in this case.